# Share instance between Java App and Web App

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8, instances, embedded-tomcat-8

I have some personal project where I am trying to share some class instance between webapp and a normal app. My project structure is something like below:
     + NormalApp
     + WebApp
I am starting the application from the NormalApp and I included WebApp using EmbeddedTomcat. Now I have a class named Notifier in WebApp. I want to use the instance of Notifier in NormalApp without losing it's state.

Could someone tell me how can I achieve this scenario?

I have some plan in mind like setting the Tomcat class loader to use Systems class loader. I tried it but couldn't able to achieve it. Is my understanding of this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making your normal app like web components ? so your application will be available when tomcat start. And you can use System properties to pass parameters to the tomcat.

Another option is using Spring boot. Here is a tutorial

https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/

Comment: Hi Reos,
I can't move normal application like we component. My usecase is to make both of them communicate each other. Can you tell me how I can pass system variables and what variables should I pass?
FYI, I don't have springs in my projects at all.

Comment: The idea is that you set the system properties in the class that launch your tomcat. Here there is a tutorial about system propeties and envioment variables http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/misc-system/environment-variables.shtml

Comment: You can set a property with System.setProperty("myProperty", value);

Comment: Hi Reos,
I know how to set system properties. What I am trying to understand is to make tomcat, work what all the properties do we need to set

Comment: I think you can share the same instance of the class between two applications. But you can have two instance of the same class with the same state in both applications. You can use a property file to load the state of that class, or can use system properties to pass the data at the applications start. Or you can have only one instace of the class in one of the applications and expose the functinality through a service. You can also can use a common file or database to share data between the two applications.

Comment: I don't want it to be like that. I wanted to share the instance only for some reason